# Why SendKeys.SendWait() crashes my application

Tags: c#, thread-safety, messaging, sendkeys

In my console application, `SendKeys.SendWait("^c")` is called to copy some selected text to the clipboard.

It works fine, but if my console application has focus when this is called, then, instead of throwing an exception, it just closes my application. And then after that things start acting up, like my mouse wheel affecting the zoom instead of scrolling up and down.

Why dose this happen.

Comment: Look what happens if you normally press ctrl-C while your console application has focus (before Windows 10 at least). As for the other part, note that if your application closes, it never gets a chance to release ctrl.

Comment: @chris I just did what you said and my application closed as usual. So is `ctrl + c` a Visual studio shortcut and can I fix this

Comment: Ctrl-C is an [OS signal for console processes to end](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The `Console` class can override this with [TreatControlCAsInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.treatcontrolcasinput(v=vs.110).aspx) or the CancelKeyPress event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctrl+c`is the signal for a Console window to close.

And the reason the mouse wheel is affecting zoom after it closes is because the application never got a chance to release the ctrl key.

This can be fixed by changing the ConsoleMode or changeing the `Console.TreatControlCAsInput` Property.

Thanks for the help